# Preventing Outlook from hiding/deleting my appointment e-mails?

Tags: email, outlook, calendar

When I receive an appointment or meeting invitation in Outlook I am given the option to accept or decline it. If I accept the appointment the event is added to my calendar and the e-mail disappears from my inbox. Is it possible to prevent the e-mail from disappearing?

I know I can find the event in the calendar, but I would like to keep the original invitation as well.

Note: I am using Outlook 2003.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have Outlook 2002 and this is in

Tools > Options

then

Preferences Tab > Email Options > Advanced Email Options

There is a check box called "Delete meeting request from Inbox when responding"

If it's the same in 2003, I'd uncheck that!

Answer (score 1):

All incoming events are automatically sent to the **"Sent"** folder once they're accepted, declined, or set as tentative.  You could just get access it from there, or create a filter to archive this once the action has taken place.